# Draw a function $g$ such that $g$ is defined on the interval $[-9,9]$

Tags: calculus, limits, graphing-functions

Sketch a function $g$ such that $g$ is defined on the interval $[-9,9]$ and satisfies the following properties:

**a)** $g(-5) = 1$, but $\lim_{x \to -5} g(x)$ does not exist.
**b)** $\lim_{x \to 1} g(x) = 2$, but $g(1)$ can't equal $2$.
**c)** $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)$ does not exist.

I'm new to limits and graphing limits so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the question said: $lim_{x\rightarrow 5} g(x)$ does not exist? Are you sure it isn't supposed to be $-5$?

Comment: You are correct. Just changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to let go of the impression that graphics must be all nice and continuous. I'll give the ideas locally.

For **a)** think of the graphic of $\frac{1}{x}$ near zero. The function is not defined on zero, and the limit does not exist there. At the point $x = -5$, make something similar, *make the lateral limits different*, that is, the graph should, say, jump at this point. Like, a horizontal line ($\neq 1$) until it gets to $x = -5$, then make $g(-5) = 1$, and finally, another horizontal line after.

For **b)**, the same idea for **a)** will do, take any graph, and make a point "jump" at $x = 1$.

For **c)**, same as **a)**.

Comment: Okay, thanks. How do I know where the graph comes from and where it is going, so how do I know if it is curved, if it comes from the left, from the right, etc?

Comment: You don't. You can do everything you like, as long as near the problematic points you try to mimic the situations I said. There are infinite answers to this problem, and you have plenty of freedom to use your creativity.

Comment: So for instance, my first point would be an open dot at (-5, 0), then have a closed dot at (-5, 1)? I'm not sure how to get the coordinate points.

Comment: Don't stress yourself trying to write the function. The exercise just ask to sketch it, so you needn't worry about coordinates. You can draw anything, just being careful with the points I said earlier. To solve this, in some stage of the drawing, you'll have to take the pen off the paper, and then continue drawing separately.

Comment: Okay, so the overall shape of the graph doesn't matter at this point?

Comment: It is completely irrelevant. Just do the situations close to the asked points, and then, whatever, join everything by straight lines. It is only important **close** to those points.

Comment: Okay, are lim x-> -5 g(x) points located at (-5, 0) then? Because there is no y coordinate actually defined. So in part a where it says "but lim x-> -5 g(x) does not exist" this would just be an open dot at (-5, 0)?

Comment: No, what you said would mean that $\lim_{x \to -5} g(x) \neq g(-5)$. It means that the point "jumped" from the graph. For the limit to not exist, one possibility is that $\lim_{x \to -5^+} g(x) \neq \lim_{x \ to -5^-} g(x)$. Look up *lateral limits*, it may help you understand the problem better.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the help!

Comment: @androidguy might have an easier time looking up [*one-sided* limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit), which is the terminology I'm more familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

This is very contrived, but here's a piece-wise function satsfying all of your conditions:

$g(x)=\begin{cases} 1 \ &\mbox{if}  -9\leq x \leq -5 
\\
\\ 1.5 \  &\mbox{if}  -5<x<0
\\
\\ 2 \ &\mbox{if}\  0 \leq x<1
\\
\\ 10 \ &\mbox{if} \ x=1
\\
\\ 2 \ &\mbox{if} \ 1<x \leq 9\end{cases}$

Your jobs:

- Draw the graph of this function
- Determine how the conditions that you've given ($a)$, $b)$ and $c)$) are satisfied in this function.

Comment: How did you get the 1, 1.5, 2, 10, 2 values? Are those just for graphing purposes to get a drawing.

Comment: It just means that $g$ attains these values at specific $x$-values. I made them up. There are infinitely many functions satisfying your criteria.

Comment: Try drawing this- it should consist of a few horizontal lines and a single point of discontinuity.